# How to pixel constrain Button Appearance given as images?

Tags: image, button

Using the images:

```
images = Uncompress["1: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"]
```

the following buttons appears without scaling in a list:

```
buttons = MapThread[Button["", Appearance -> {"Default" -> #, "Pressed" -> #2}] &, images]
```

However when putting them in a `Multicolumn`, they scale badly to match sizes.

```
Multicolumn[buttons, 1]
```

[image]

I want them to align center left with the same size as they appear in the `List`.
Neither `Magnification -> 1` in the images nor `Grid` with `Alignment -> Left` fixed it.
How to make a grid of such buttons without scaling images?

All images have the same vertical size if that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
buttons = MapThread[Button["", Appearance -> {"Default" -> #, "Pressed" -> #2}, 
    ImageSize -> All] &, images]
```

[image]

```
Multicolumn[buttons, 1]
```

[image]